# Sketch3 Mirror - Change Localhost from port 8080

Tags: port, mirror, sketch-3

im using a node server to build a localhost version of a website. But everytime I open sketch to work on a new icon sketch3 mirror takes control of the same port '8080' meaning I can only view my site when I close sketch3.

Is there a way to move the sketch3 browser mirror server to another port?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do 2 things:

1. Update sketch to version 43.2 +
2. In your Terminal type `defaults write com.bohemiancoding.sketch3.plist mirrorWebPort -int 9234`